# Run league but with no admin rights and one dll not working

Tags: windows-10, gaming

So I got league of legends on my laptop but I do not have admin rights and I was wondering if I could find a way to play. The client works fine until after champion selection after which the game switches to the actual exe then It gives me an dll related error saying d3_dx9_39 is missing and it puts me back on the league client with the reconnect button. Is there a way around this just wondering, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask the admin. That's what they're for. We will not assist you in circumventing security protocols.

Comment: The file belong to DX9 which means it’s not installed which means without being an Administrator it cannot be installed